# Calcular taxa de juros com JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Não estou conseguindo calcular a taxa de juros de uma variável com JavaScript (*Comecei a estudar hoje*)

Segue o código:

```html
<h1>FORMULÁRIO</h1>
<label for ="id">Id</label>
<input id ="id" name ="id" type="number" ng-model="cadastro.id"/>
<br>
<br>
<label for ="nome">Nome Cliente</label>
<input id ="nome" name ="nome" type="text" ng-model="cadastro.nome"/>
<br>
<br>
<label for ="limite">Limite de Crédito</label>
<input id ="limite" name ="limite" type="number" ng-model="cadastro.limiteCredito"/>
<br>
<br>
<label for ="risco">Risco</label>
<input id ="risco" name ="risco" type="text" ng-model="cadastro.risco"/>
<br>
<br>
<button ng-click="salvar(cadastro)"> SALVAR </button>
<button ng-click="cancelar(cadastro)"> CANCELAR </button>
<br>
<br>
</form>
```

```js
$scope.salvar = function (cadastro) {

    /*
     *Lógica para podermos utilizar a function Editar.
     */
    var achouCadastro = false;
    for (var i = 0, length = cadastros.length; i < length; i++) {
        if (cadastros[i].id === cadastro.id) {
            cadastros[i].nome = cadastro.nome;
            cadastros[i].limiteCredito = cadastro.limiteCredito;
            cadastros[i].risco = cadastro.risco;
            achouCadastro = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (!achouCadastro) {

        /*
         * Lógica para calcular a taxa de juros 
         */

        var valorJuros = cadastro.risco.value;
        var limiteComJuros = number(cadastro.limiteCredito.value);
        if (valorJuros === "A") {
            return limiteComJuros;
        } else if (valorJuros === "B") {
            limiteComJuros = cadastro.limiteCredito + cadastro.limiteCredito * 0, 1;
        } else {
            limiteComJuros = cadastro.limiteCredito + cadastro.limiteCredito * 0, 2;
        } 
        cadastros.push(cadastro);

    }
    $scope.cadastro = {};

};
```

Meu `if .. else` não está funcionando. Alguém poderia me dar uma luz?

Comment: Crie uma variável valorComJuros que calcula o valor de um boleto acrescido de 10% de juros por atraso;

Answer (score 0):

Vi que está tentando utilizar a função para estocar os valores em arrays posteriormente, porém, o cálculo de juros tendo como base os dados que foram inseridos no campo de formulário, a lógica simples seria :

```
var valorJuros = cadastro.risco.value;
        var limiteComJuros = parseFloat(cadastro.limiteCredito.value);
        if (valorJuros === "A") {
            return limiteComJuros;
        } else if (valorJuros === "B") {
            limiteComJuros = cadastro.limiteCredito + cadastro.limiteCredito * 0.1;
        } else {
            limiteComJuros = cadastro.limiteCredito + cadastro.limiteCredito * 0.2;
        }
```

1. parseFloat() vai retornar sempre em número, pois assim não corre o risco de apanhar valores ao qual o JS não conseguirá calcular
2. Multiplicar qualquer valor e data por 0 (cadastro.limiteCredito * 0, 1), terá como resultado, 0.

**Se a lógica acima não for o que procura, comente a lógica ao qual espera os resultados e tentarei refazer o código para ajudá-lo.**